# How to hide my website port number on website url

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, tomcat

My website has implemented by using JAVA. So we have taken VPS and installed Tomcat then deployed My website is appearing like this

whenever I click www.mysite.com in url ... it is appearing as below.

http://mysite.com:8080/foldername/

But I would like to see my website as www.mysite.com

Can any one suggest me what to do .. should I do any changes in htaccess file ?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the port number to 80 in tomcat config. Port 80 is the only port which browsers hide because it's the default port.

Navigate to [your-tomcat-root]/conf/server.xml and then change

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

to

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```